# codename one image from url

Tags: java, image, url, codenameone

I am trying to make a mobile app using Java and codename one plugin. My question is - what's the simples way to populate an image from a URL to a label? I Googled it and all I found was this piece of code:

```
Image i = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "fileNameInStorage", "http://xxx/myurl.jpg", URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
```

But I have no idea how to use it. What is a `placeholder`? It asks an `EncodedImage` parameter, but if I do:

```
EncodedImage image = new EncodedImage(10, 10);
```

I get the error that `EncodedImage` is protected.

I simply want to populate an image from a URL to my desired label in a form.

I am using GUI builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placeholder image is the image that should show while the image from URL is being downloaded and it's an EncodedImage.

If your Label already have an icon as a placeholder, you can use its icon, otherwise you can create a new placeholder image. Below are 3 options to create an EncodedImage and a URLImage usage example:

**Method 1:**

```
//generate a grey placeholder that matches the size of the label's icon
Image placeholder = Image.createImage(label.getIcon().getWidth(), label.getIcon().getWidth(), 0xbfc9d2);
EncodedImage encImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(placeholder, false);
```

**Method 2:**

```
//Convert the label icon to EncodedImage
EncodedImage encImage = (EncodedImage)label.getIcon();
```

**Method 3:**

```
//Create a fresh grey EncodedImage when label doesn't have any icon set initially
int deviceWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
Image placeholder = Image.createImage(deviceWidth / 10, deviceWidth / 10, 0xbfc9d2); //square image set to 10% of screen width
EncodedImage encImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(placeholder, false);
```

**Usage Example:**

It's a good practice to use the URL as the cached image name in storage. If you have a multiple sizes of the same image, just prefix them with a unique string like `"Large" + URL`

```
 label.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(encImage, "Medium_" + "http://xxx/myurl.jpg", "http://xxx/myurl.jpg", URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));
```